# How to cancel the effect of RequestWindowFeature in android\monodroid?

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.android

I write game. I use `RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);` at splash screen, but how can I disable it at settings screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings activity onCreate, run this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setTitle("Settings");
```

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding code in Mono would be

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
Window.SetTitle("Settings");
```